# Photoshop jsx image grid

Tags: photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

What I am ultimately trying to do is to create a grid of images for print that are minor variations of the same thing (different text is all).  Looking through online resources I was able to create a script that changes the text and exports all of the images necessary (several hundred).  What I am trying to do now is to import all of these images into a new photoshop document and lay them all out in a grid and I can't seem to find any examples of this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to place a file at a specific coordinate (I'm using CS5 and have the design suite so if there is a way in illustrator to do this quickly...)?

Also, I'm open to other ideas on how to do this (even other programs) easily.  It's for labels so the positioning on the sheet has to be pretty precise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The art layer object has a translate() method that takes delta x and y params.  You'll need to open each image, copy it to the target document, get its current location (using artLayer.bounds) and do the math to find the deltas to position it where you want it.  Your deltas can be in pixels so you'll get plenty of precision.

Check out your 'JavaScript Scripting Reference' pdf in your Adobe install directory for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'm marking Anna's response as the answer because though I didn't fully test it, it seems like it should work and answers the original question with jsx.  However I'm also leaving my final solution in case anyone else runs across this with the same issue and may prefer this method as well.

What I ended up doing instead is using InDesign.  I figured out that it has a grid option that lets you import a number of files and place them all in an equal grid in a single command.  This is almost exactly what I was looking for, except that it leaves a small border/margin in between the columns and grids and mine were designed to meet exactly.

I couldn't figure out how to make it not have the border (I have very little experience with InDesign, it may be possible).  However I was able to select all my images and scale them uniformly to be the correct size, then I just selected each column and dragged it over to snap to the adjacent column and the same with rows...